# maximum product of distances of a point and vertices of equilateral triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, maximum-principle

If $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle. $P$ is a variable point inside the triangle or on its sides. We need to find the maximum product of $AP \cdot BP \cdot CP$.

This question is in a Complex Analysis homework.
I don't know how can I use the complex analysis (maybe, maximum modulus theorem ) to find the maximum product.

Updated work

Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ and $z$ correspond to the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, and variable point $p$, respectively, then the product function is given by
$f(z)=|z-z_1||z-z_2||z-z_3|$, clearly, $(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)$ is nonconstant holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ and so in $\overline{T}$, where $T$ represents the region inside the equilateral triangle. Then by the Maximum modulus Theorem, $f$ attains the maximum on the boundary $\partial T$. To this point, is there a way to find $z$ explicitly that maximize $f$?

Comment: Given one vertex and the side (base?), the third vertex may be calculated. For the purpose of finding P assume side = 2.  (0,0) and (2,0) is the base. Find the third vertex and for a point (x,y) in the triangle write the equation of multiplication. Find maximum by means derivatives.

Comment: @Moti, this using Calculus, is there a way to apply the complex analysis theorems/contents?

Comment: Define the vertices as COMPLEX values, but you still need derivatives.

Comment: @Moti One can solve the issue in a geometric way without needing derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Up to a similitude $s(z)=az+b$, we can reduce the issue to equilateral triangle $T$ with vertices:

$$z_1=1, \ \ z_2=\omega, \ \ z_3=\omega^2=\overline{\omega} \ \ \text{with} \ \ \omega=e^{2i \pi/3} $$

Therefore: AP.BP.CP is the absolute value of :

$$(z-1)(z-\omega)(z-\omega^2)=z^3-1$$

The maximum value of this holomorphic function, call it $f(z)$, is reached for a $z$ belonging to the boundary (Maximum Modulus Theorem, as you have noticed). Let us parametrize the line segment from $1$ to $\omega$ in the following way:

$$z=(1-t)+t \omega, \ \ \ \ 0\le t \le 1\tag{1}$$

The image by $f$ of this line segment is the red "drop-like" cubic curve (see equation in the remark below).

The two other sides

$$z'=(1-t)\omega+t \omega^2, \ \  z''=(1-t)\omega^2+t$$

can be written under the form:

$$z'=\omega z, \ \  z''=\omega^2 z \tag{1}$$

Therefore, because $\omega^3=1$ and $(\omega^2)^3=1$, the image by $f$ of these two other sides obtained by taking to the third power expressions (1) gives the **same** curve!

This is the image $f(\partial T)$. The image by function $f$ of $T$ itself is the inside of the drop. The sister curve described as the image of $\partial T$ by $g(z):=z^3$ is magenta curve.

Considering the red curve, $f(z)=z^3-1$ reaches its maximal value for $z_m^3-1=I'$, which corresponds to:

$$z_m^3=-\tfrac18 \ \ \text{(point I')} \tag{2}$$

Cubic equation (2) has three solutions. As the argument of $I$ is $\pi+k 2 \pi$, the arguments of solutions $z_m$ must be $\pi/3 + k 2 \pi/3$. As the maximum must occur on the boundary, taking $k=0,1,2$ gives points $J_0, J_1, J_2$ resp., i.e., the midpoints of the sides of triangle $T$.

[image]

Fig. 1: The three maximizing solutions $J_0, J_1, J_2$.

**Remark:** The parametric equations of the "drop" obtained by taking the real and imaginary parts of $((1-t)+t \omega)^3$ are

$$(x=1-\tfrac92 t(1-t), \ \ \ y=\tfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}t(1-t)(1-2t))$$

Comment: I just realized that the "droplike curve" belongs to the family of (cubic) Bezier curves.